# Upload CSV file in Mui-Datatables

Tags: reactjs, mui-datatable

How to upload CSV file in Mui-Datatables and display in the table?
I am new to Mui-Datatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to upload CSV files to [MUI Datatables](https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables) is to use the npm package [React-Papaparse](https://react-papaparse.js.org/).

I have set up a [Code Sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-driscoll-zge0b?file=/src/CSVUploader.jsx) as an example of how it could be set up.

#### MockData.csv

```
name,city,company,state
Hansiain Babar,Richmond,Mybuzz,Virginia
Carissa Lenormand,Pittsburgh,Yambee,Pennsylvania
Weber Skeath,Young America,Mymm,Minnesota
Ashton Pashan,Loretto,Brainsphere,Minnesota
Willi Martignoni,Minneapolis,Realmix,Minnesota
Aarika Philippart,Tacoma,Fadeo,Washington
Crichton Worpole,Inglewood,Edgetag,California
Marna Climer,Colorado Springs,Flashspan,Colorado
Gilemette Arington,Amarillo,Trudeo,Texas
Maryanne Gostage,Richmond,Skyba,Virginia
```

#### CSVUploader.jsx

This is essentially pulled from the React-Paparse Docs, but with the config={{headers: true}}:

```js
import React from "react";
import { CSVReader } from "react-papaparse";

const buttonRef = React.createRef();

const CSVReader1 = (props) => {
  const { setCSVData } = props;
  const handleOpenDialog = (e) => {
    // Note that the ref is set async, so it might be null at some point
    if (buttonRef.current) {
      buttonRef.current.open(e);
    }
  };

  const handleOnFileLoad = (data) => {
    console.log("---------------------------");
    console.log(data);
    /* *** When the headers config option is set to 'true', it 
    returns an empty object as the last item in the array, 
    so we need to remove it: *** */
    data.pop();
    setCSVData(data);
    console.log("---------------------------");
  };

  const handleOnError = (err, file, inputElem, reason) => {
    console.log("---------------------------");
    console.log(err);
    console.log("---------------------------");
  };

  const handleOnRemoveFile = (data) => {
    console.log("---------------------------");
    console.log(data);
    console.log("---------------------------");
  };

  const handleRemoveFile = (e) => {
    // Note that the ref is set async, so it might be null at some point
    if (buttonRef.current) {
      buttonRef.current.removeFile(e);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h5>Basic Upload</h5>
      <CSVReader
        ref={buttonRef}
        onFileLoad={handleOnFileLoad}
        onError={handleOnError}
        noClick
        noDrag
        config={{ header: true }}
        onRemoveFile={handleOnRemoveFile}
      >
        {({ file }) => (
          <aside
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              flexDirection: "row",
              marginBottom: 10
            }}
          >
            <button
              type="button"
              onClick={handleOpenDialog}
              style={{
                borderRadius: 0,
                marginLeft: 0,
                marginRight: 0,
                width: "40%",
                paddingLeft: 0,
                paddingRight: 0
              }}
            >
              Browse file
            </button>
            <div
              style={{
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderStyle: "solid",
                borderColor: "#ccc",
                height: 45,
                lineHeight: 2.5,
                marginTop: 5,
                marginBottom: 5,
                paddingLeft: 13,
                paddingTop: 3,
                width: "60%"
              }}
            >
              {file && file.name}
            </div>
            <button
              style={{
                borderRadius: 0,
                marginLeft: 0,
                marginRight: 0,
                paddingLeft: 20,
                paddingRight: 20
              }}
              onClick={handleRemoveFile}
            >
              Remove
            </button>
          </aside>
        )}
      </CSVReader>
    </>
  );
};

export default CSVReader1;
```

#### CustomToolbar.jsx

Here, we have a customToolbar component, which is basically the same a the default toolbar but with an extra button we will add to upload the CSV file:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import Tooltip from "@material-ui/core/Tooltip";
import AddCircleOutlineIcon from "@material-ui/icons/AddCircleOutline";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Modal from "@material-ui/core/Modal";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

import CSVUploader from "./CSVUploader.jsx";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  paper: {
    margin: "0 auto",
    top: "25vh",
    position: "relative",
    width: 400,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    border: "2px solid #000",
    boxShadow: theme.shadows[5],
    padding: theme.spacing(2, 4, 3)
  }
}));

const CustomToolbar = (props) => {
  const { setDataForTable } = props;
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [CSVData, setCSVData] = useState([]);

  // When CSVData is updated, parse it and pass it up to the Table:
  useEffect(() => {
    const dataArr = Array.from(CSVData).map((data) => {
      // Make sure values are truth before returning:
      if (data.data.name && data.data.city) {
        return {
          name: data.data.name,
          company: data.data.company,
          city: data.data.city,
          state: data.data.state
        };
      }
    });
    setDataForTable(dataArr);
  }, [CSVData, setDataForTable]);

  // Open and close modal
  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  /* Custom Button to open upload modal */
  return (
    <>
      <Tooltip title={"Add data from CSV"}>
        <IconButton>
          <AddCircleOutlineIcon onClick={handleOpen} />
        </IconButton>
      </Tooltip>
      <Modal
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="simple-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="simple-modal-description"
      >
        <div className={classes.paper}>
          <h2 id="simple-modal-title">Upload CSV Data</h2>
          <CSVUploader setCSVData={setCSVData} />
          <Button onClick={handleClose}>Close Modal</Button>
        </div>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};

export default CustomToolbar;
```

#### Table.jsx

And here, we pass the customToolbar component to the table options:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import MUIDataTable from "mui-datatables";
import CustomToolbar from "./CustomToolbar.jsx";

const columns = [
  {
    name: "name",
    label: "Name",
    options: {
      filter: true,
      sort: true
    }
  },
  {
    name: "company",
    label: "Company",
    options: {
      filter: true,
      sort: true
    }
  },
  {
    name: "city",
    label: "City",
    options: {
      filter: true,
      sort: true
    }
  },
  {
    name: "state",
    label: "State",
    options: {
      filter: true,
      sort: true
    }
  }
];

const Table = () => {
  // Parse csv data from CustomToolbar:
  const [dataForTable, setDataForTable] = useState();

  // Custom Table options with custom toolbar:
  const options = {
    filterType: "checkbox",
    customToolbar: () => {
      return <CustomToolbar setDataForTable={setDataForTable} />;
    }
  };

  // Table
  return (
    <MUIDataTable
      title={"Employee List"}
      data={dataForTable}
      columns={columns}
      options={options}
    />
  );
};

export default Table;
```

Answer (score 1):

As of now, there is not yet an existing feature in MUI DataTable but it would be a great feature request.

A workaround would be defining your own function that parses the CSV file that returns an array of headers and an array of objects of row records. The result could be passed through props

`<MUIDataTable title={"Employee List"} data={myData} columns={myColumns} options={options} />`

where `myData` and `myColumns` have the records and headers of the CSV file.